# how to pass latitude and longitude data to navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i am getting null data on my recyclerview, i am passing latitude and longitude data using place picker, its working properly on my MapActivity. but when i m trying to store that data on my NavigationDrawer item activity, its getting null,

here is my code of MapActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        try {
            manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            } else {
                mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        initialize();
        setupDrawer();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSerch);
        assert search != null;
        search.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSerch) {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

                final Double latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                final Double longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                final String placeName = String.valueOf(place.getName());
                final float radius = 0.5f;

                LatLng loc2 = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                marker2 = new MarkerOptions().position(loc2).title(placeName).visible(true);
                mMap.addMarker(marker2);
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        try {
            mDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.mNavDrawer);
            assert mDrawer != null;
            mDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.string.DrawerOpen,
                    R.string.DrawerClose);
            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = null;
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_1) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LocationList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_2) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            intent = new Intent(this, AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_3) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            intent = new Intent(this, Help.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In my LocationList class i have recycleview and i m trying to set latitude logtitude data on it. how do i do that.

here is my code of LocationListActivity

```
  public class LocationList extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Locations> locationsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LocationAdapter mAdapter;
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    String placeName;
    Double latitude, longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_list);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new LocationAdapter(locationsList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

       prepareLocationData();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                placeName = String.valueOf(place.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private void prepareLocationData() {
        Locations locations = new Locations(placeName, latitude, longitude);
        locationsList.add(locations);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

when i run the code, its getting null, i dont know how to pass data, plz help me.. here is my cardview image.

[image: cardview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the parameters to your intent and retrieve them in your LocationActivity.

Please see below :

**Set parameters to your intent**

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = null;
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_item_1) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LocationList.class);
            intent.putExtra("longitude_key", longitude);
            intent.putExtra("latitude_key", latitude);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

**Retrieve the parameters in your LocationActivity**

```
          ...

 Double latitude, longitude;

 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_list);


        if (getIntent() != null) {
            longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude_key", 0); // set to 0 if not found
            latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude_key", 0); // set to 0 if not found
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: wow.. its work, but there is a problem... when i restart my app my cardview is showing null again. where i have to used sharepreference..? and how..

Comment: Yes, you have to store the information in the shared preferences. When you open the app again, you need to read from the shared preferences and set your values.

If you are happy with my answer below. Please put it as resolved and upvote it !

Thanks so much :)